# Hotkey that will show the 'Debug Console' panel but without activating it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

About 90% of the time, I am just using the debug console to output strings and display objects. The majority of the time I don't interact with it.

So I just need a way of showing it, for those instances when its hidden.

The  following hotkey when triggered, does show the debug console but it takes focus from wherever it is currently at:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+y",
  "command": "workbench.debug.action.toggleRepl",
  "when": "workbench.panel.repl.view.active"}
}
```

I tried creating my own custom solution that consists of two steps:

1. Show the debug console
2. Navigate back to where keyboard focus was at

This first attempt shows and/or activates the debug console but then instead of going back to the editor that was active, it jumps back to the editor that was active before that editor:

```
{
    "key": "5",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args":{
        "commands": [
        "workbench.panel.repl.view.focus",                              //shows and activates the debug console
        "workbench.action.navigateBackInNavigationLocations"        //takes focus to the editor before the current editor
        ]
    }
},
```

This second attempt appears to be functionally identical to the first one, even though I am using `workbench.action.navigateBack`:

```
{
    "key": "6",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args":{
        "commands": [
        "workbench.panel.repl.view.focus",                              //shows and activates the debug console
        "workbench.action.navigateBack"                                 //takes focus to the editor before the current editor
        ]
    }
},
```

Looking around I did find a command that describes what I want to do but binding it to a key and attempting to trigger does nothing:

```
{
    "key": "5",
    "command": "workbench.panel.repl.view.toggleVisibility"
}
```

If some genius out there know a way to do this, please share it with me.